# Report Viewer in VB.NET 2005

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone please help me with the code as to how i can use stored procedures with parameters to retrieve data and display it in a report viewer in VB 2005.

Please help me with the connection part as well.

Regards,
George

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at the [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) class.

This code project article seems like a good place to start: [Using the ASP.NET 2.0 ReportViewer in Local Mode](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ReportViewer.aspx)

Quote from the article: *So here is an article on how to generate reports using the ASP.NET 2.0 ReportViewer web server control via Local Mode with a parameterized stored procedure*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please help me with working with Report Viewer in VB.NET 2005.

Comment: @George: Sorry, I'm not an expert in it or anything like that. I suggest starting with the article in the link in my answer and then if you get stuck on anything you post a new question about that specific thing. You'll probably get more responses if you have more specific questions.